# Añadir Imagen de perfil al Auth register de laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Quisiera añadir al código que sale por defecto al crear el login de Laravel una imagen de perfil, pero el codigo no se parece en nada a lo que uso en el resto de controladores, la pagina esta online y no puedo ponerme a hacer pruebas porque el cliente no quiere que caiga la pagina.

este es el register.blade.php (esta sin modificar tal y como aparece al ejecutar el comando y el codigo comentado es lo que he añadido pero no se terminar en el controller).

```php
<div class="container">
    <div class="row justify-content-center">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="card">
                <div class="card-header">{{ __('Register') }}</div>

                <div class="card-body">
                    <form method="POST" action="{{ route('register') }}">
                        @csrf

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Nombre') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="name" type="text" class="form-control @error('name') is-invalid @enderror" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}" required autocomplete="name" autofocus>

                                @error('name')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <!--<div class="form-group row">
                            <lavel for="urlImg" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Img') }}</lavel>
                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="urlImg" type="file" class="form-control @error('urlImg') is-invalid @enderror" name="urlImg" placeholder="Img" required autocomplete="urlImg">
                            </div>
                        </div>-->

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control @error('email') is-invalid @enderror" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" required autocomplete="email">

                                @error('email')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control @error('password') is-invalid @enderror" name="password" required autocomplete="new-password">

                                @error('password')
                                    <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                        <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                    </span>
                                @enderror
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row">
                            <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                            <div class="col-md-6">
                                <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                            <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                                    {{ __('Register') }}
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Y ese es el RegisterController.php:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\User;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Hash;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Validator;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\RegistersUsers;
use Storage;
use Image;

class RegisterController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Register Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles the registration of new users as well as their
    | validation and creation. By default this controller uses a trait to
    | provide this functionality without requiring any additional code.
    |
    */

    use RegistersUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after registration.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }

    /**
     * Get a validator for an incoming registration request.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\Validator
     */
    protected function validator(array $data)
    {
        return Validator::make($data, [
            'name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
            'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
        ]);
    }

    /**
     * Create a new user instance after a valid registration.
     *
     * @param  array  $data
     * @return \App\User
     */
    protected function create(array $data)
    {
        return User::create([
            'name' => $data['name'],
            'email' => $data['email'],
            'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        ]);
    }
}
```

Yo habitualmente el nombre de la imagen lo hago con un request en el objeto de la tabla y la imagen en si lo hago con un Image::make, esta es la primera vez que me aventuro a hacer el login con el comando auth de laravel y no se como modificarlo

Answer (score 0):

Lo primero es hacer una migración para el nuevo campo y ejecutarla con `php artisan migrate`

```
 public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->string('avatar')->default('default.png');
        });
    }
```

En la vista tienes que añadir un campo nuevo para subirla

```
   <input type="file" name="avatar" id="avatarFile">
```

Y en el create pues lo cambias para subir el avatar

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    $request = app('request');
    if($request->hasfile('avatar')){
        $avatar = $request->file('avatar');
        $filename = time() . '.' . $avatar->getClientOriginalExtension();
        Image::make($avatar)->resize(300, 300)->save( public_path('/uploads/avatars/' . $filename) );
    }
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),
        'avatar' => $filename,
    ]);
}
```

(En este caso se guardan en la public, pero si es información sensible o no quieres que se vea, lo idóneo es hacerlo en la privada)